# show who resit and passed and what course was it?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, case

i need help find who fail in exam & resit and pass the exam only,

heres the code:

```
select STUDENT_ID,EXAM_ID,SCORE,PASS_THRESHOLD,s.NAME , c.NAME as Course_name, EXAM_DT, 
case 
 when SCORE>=PASS_THRESHOLD then 'PASS'
 else 'Fail'
end as Flag
from exam_submission es 
left join student s  on es.STUDENT_ID  = s.ID
left join exam e    on es.EXAM_ID  = e.ID 
left join course c  on e.COURSE_ID  = c.ID
```

heres the result:

```
STUDENT_ID  EXAM_ID SCORE   PASS_THRESHOLD  NAME    Course_name     EXAM_DT      Flag
    1          3      88    65           Anthony    Data Mining     2019-12-17   PASS
    1          5      71    70           Anthony    Statistic       2019-12-19   PASS
    2          1      53    55           Sisca      Machine Learning2019-12-17  Fail
    2          3      77    65           Sisca      Data Mining     2019-12-17  PASS
    2          4      85    63           Sisca      Data Science    2019-12-18  PASS
    2          1      60    55           Sisca      Machine Learning2020-01-08  PASS
```

I need find like this:

```
 2         1      53    55           Sisca      Machine Learning2019-12-17  Fail
 2         1      60    55           Sisca      Machine Learning2020-01-08  PASS
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: It's good programming practice to _qualify_ **all** columns. at least when writing multi-table queries. Just like `es.STUDENT_ID` instead of just `STUDENT_ID`.

Comment: Do you really need LEFT JOIN's?

Comment: i using mysql,  yes i still forgot qualify i column, yes i really need left join to get exam treshold & course name

Comment: But your expected result contains no null values, looks just like a regular INNER JOIN result.

Comment: yes, i just do the step like that, but what should i do from that step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly using a query like below.
this is using your query as input.
Also we have assumed that it is not possible to have a student have (PASS, FAIL) for a student on same exam on two years chronologically.

```
; with inputdata as 
(
 select STUDENT_ID,EXAM_ID,SCORE,PASS_THRESHOLD,s.NAME , c.NAME as Course_name, EXAM_DT, 
    case 
     when SCORE>=PASS_THRESHOLD then 'PASS'
     else 'Fail'
    end as Flag
    from exam_submission es 
    left join student s  on es.STUDENT_ID  = s.ID
    left join exam e    on es.EXAM_ID  = e.ID 
    left join course c  on e.COURSE_ID  = c.ID
)
    
 select * from Inputdata I
join 
 ( select student_id, exam_id from 
    inputdata 
    group by student_id, exam_id
    having count(distinct flag)=2
)T on I.student_id=T.student_id and I.exam_id=T.exam_id
order by exam_dt asc
```

Comment: i try your query, but when select student_id, exam_id, from input data, there are no sugestion to table, so the syntax became error like this :       




SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 12

Comment: @ashhab there's a typo I've corrected it

Comment: @ashhab There was an extra comma after exam_id before like `exam_id, from` . I changed that to `exam_id from`  now. Please try now.

Comment: yes seems work, but the problem now is 
SQL Error [1146] [42S02]: Table 'univ.Inputdata' doesn't exist, the db does'nt allow to edit, only view

Comment: after finding the typo space in first line,  it actually work, thanks for your advice